# stenciljs and vue-output-target requires two builds?

Tags: stenciljs

I'm using @stencil/vue-output-target 0.8.7 with @stencil/core 4.12.2 to create a vue-library folder in my dist folder when I do `npm run build`. The problem is that I have to do run the build twice.

The first time I do `npm run build` I get the cli output that it is generating the vue-library and there are no errors.  But when I look in the dist folder, there's no vue-library folder.

I run `npm run build` a second time, no errors, and the same output to the command line.  But now when I look in the dist folder the vue-library folder is there and has all of the files in it.

This is part of my stencil.config.ts:

```
export const config: Config = {
  plugins: [
    sass({
      injectGlobalPaths: [
        '../../shared/assets/css/my-colors.css',
        '../../shared/assets/css/my-fonts.css',
      ]
    }),
  ],
  sourceMap: true,
  outputTargets: [
    vueOutputTarget({
      componentCorePackage: 'my-elements', // match 'name' field from package.json
      proxiesFile: './dist/vue-library/lib/components.ts', // file w/vue wrappers
    }),
  ],
```

If it were having trouble with the path up to my shared css, you'd think it would consistently fail.

It's almost like the first build caches something that the second build then uses.

Anyone else seeing this or know a reason?  Luckily this isn't something I need to completely automate so I can work around it.

thanks

Comment: Does this happen if you pick a directory other that `dist`?

Comment: @RyanWaskiewicz - Weird thing was that commenting out the www type actually fixed my problem.  Not sure why that would work, because the www folder gets built and updated when I do `npm run start` just fine.